# Jboss and startAsync servlet Runnable thread is not getting called

Tags: java, servlets, asynchronous

I'm running Jboss 6.4 and trying to use startAsync feature of servlet. i did web.xml changes for filter and servlet by adding tag "async-supported" true

```
// request.isAsyncSupported() is true
final AsyncContext asyncContext = request.startAsync();
asyncContext.start(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(" inside run method ..");
        asyncContext.complete(); 
    }
});
```

run method is not getting called. i don't see any error or exception in log. 
Is there any specific configuration required like thread pool configuration in JBoss to handle it? What i'm missing here?